# Publish a .Net 5.0 web in IIS from Visual Studio 2019 doesn't start

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, iis, visual-studio-2019, .net-5

I am trying to publish a test website in .Net 5.0 on an IIS on Windows 10.

- I have .Net 5.0 installed
- I have activated the IIS on Windows
- I have installed the ASP.NET Core 5.0 Runtime (v5.0.1)
- I have installed the dotnet-hosting-5.0.1-win
- I have created the web application in the IIS and assigned it a specific Pool with the .Net CLR version "No code managed" and "Integrated". I have assigned the port 8090.

From Visual Studio when Publish I selected:

- File System
- Configuration: Release
- Target Framework: 5.0
- Deployment Mode: Self-Contained
- Target Runtime: win-x86 (with win-x64 it doesn't work either)

My Windows version is 1909 (OS compilation 18363.1256)

If I navigate to the path http://localhost:8090/ I get this error "HTTP Error 500.32 - Failed to load .NET Core host.

I have reset the IIS, I have deleted and recreated the application, I have restarted Windows, but it still does not start the test web.

The Windows event viewer showed me these errors:

- Unable to load 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TestNetCore.\hostfxr.dll'. This might be caused by a bitness mismatch between IIS application pool and published application.
- Could not find 'aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll'. Exception message:
- Failed to start application '/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT', ErrorCode '0x800700c1'.

I don't know what else to look at. Any ideas or suggestions?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your errors are in ASP.NET Core, For these errors, you can try the following solutions:

- Have you install asp.net core module? if not, please install it:
  [ASP.NET Core Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-5.0)
- Open IIS manager > Application Pool > Select App pool > Advanced
  Settings, update "Enable 32 bits applications" from **false to true** > Click OK.

[image]

- Try to delete the applicationhost.config (in .vs\config\applicationHost.config) and rebuild app.

Comment: luckily, i saw this. and this worked. but what is the cause of this? My windows server is 64bits

Comment: Yes, but you choose x86 as the target platform for your build...

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem in this way for myself:

In `web.config` I remove `hostingModel="inprocess"`

I answer for others who encounter this problem

Comment: Why did this work? Thanks for your help!